# int.Parse(string) produces DateTime format exception error

Tags: c#

Can anyone please tell me why this won´t work?
I get a format exception. `int.Parse(str)` - somehow this tries to convert the string into DateTime but I want it to get an int

```
bool truncL(int val)
{
    while (val >= 1)
    {
        string str = val.ToString();
        str = str.Substring(1);                
        val = int.Parse(str);                
        if (!primeList.Exists(x => x == val)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `str` exactly when you debug your code? And what is your `CurrentCulture`? And what do you mean by _DateTime FormatException_ exactly? There is no DateTime in your code.

Comment: *int.Parse(str) - somehow this tries to convert the string into datetime* It isn't trying to create a `DateTime` object. It is simply telling you the `string` isn't valid.

Comment: Please also post the complete exception you get...

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
str = str.Substring(1);
```

Is trying to fetch the substring starting at index 1. If your integer value is 0-9, this will yield an empty string, and that is probably why your code is failing.

If you want to fetch the first digit, you want:

```
str = str.Substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: The first digit would be `str=str.Substring(0, 1);`

Comment: @juharr Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: i wanted to remove only the first digit. now i got it to work! thank you very much!

Comment: do i have to mark the question as answered or something like this?? this was my first question so i don´t know

Comment: @MarkusUnterberger You *can* mark this question as the answer if you found it useful (you don't have to otherwise). You do that by pressing the arrow under the voting counter.

Answer (score 0):

my dear friend here is your silly mistake

```
str = str.Substring(1);
```

change the statement to

```
str = str.Substring(0, 1);
```

and everything would work fine

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you very much, now it works! i should have known this! ;)